# Correlation matrix does not show all columns python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to solve the "House Prices" challenge from Kaggle and I'm stuck on my correlation matrix because it simply doesn't show all columns I want. Initially, it was obviously because of the large number of columns, so I did this:

```
df = df_data[['SalePrice', 'MSSubClass', 'MSZoning', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'Street', 'Alley', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities']].copy()    

corrmax = df.corr()

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12))
sns.heatmap(corrmax, annot = True)
```

And then, the result is a heatmap with only SalePrice, MSSubClass, LotFrontage and LotArea for some reason. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Maybe some of your columns are non-numeric? Try `print(df.dtypes)` to see.

Comment: Ouch! They're not! Now that you said it's so dumb! Lol! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you analysis the dataset of House Prices [House Prices](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) there are about 21-23 categorical variables 'MSZoning','Alley'
The corr() matrix only show their relationship between the numerical values or non-categorical variables

```
corrmax = df.corr()
```

If you want to find the relation between the categorical and non-categorical variables use need to use the [Spearman correlation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)

You will find some help from the links below...

[An overview of correlation measures between categorical and continuous variables](https://medium.com/@outside2SDs/an-overview-of-correlation-measures-between-categorical-and-continuous-variables-4c7f85610365)

[Correlation between a nominal (IV) and a continuous (DV) variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable/124618#124618)